# Fluctuation between adjacent histogram bins

Tags: python, random, histogram, binning

I want to write a code that starts from bin size of 1 and increases the bin size by 1 until the fluctuation between the adjacent bins is greater than 5%.

[Histogram code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gbRL.jpg)

Comment: Please insert the source code here instead of submitting a screenshot. [Fenced code blocks are here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks) for some years already. And what is wrong with your program? How can we help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.